# GetStatus of file shared through Parallels throws exception

Tags: windows, macos, visual-c++, virtual-machine, parallels

I'm placing a file in a shared folder on a Mac.

Then I'm trying to get the status of that file that is shared through [`Parallels`](http://www.parallels.com/uk/products/desktop/) on a Windows machine. An exception gets thrown that crashes the program if unhandled.

This only happens if the file hasn't been touched in any way on the Windows side, otherwise the operation completes normally.

Is it an issue with parallels trying to mesh the two filesystems?

```
try
{
    CFile::GetStatus (path, status);
}
catch (CException* ex)
{
    ex->ReportError();
}
catch (...)
{
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit about what error message you're seeing?

Comment: Welcome to the world of VM file sharing, where it kinda works sometimes... I've never used Parallels, but I've used VMWare and VirtualBox and both of those are similar in that most things work but it isn't quite there. I've especially noticed issues with things such as compilers and Windows Installer.

Comment: Maybe the comment comes somewhat late, but I have experienced similar problems on Windows 10 opening files on a shared folder which resided on a NAS. Apparently it might be related to incorrect system time settings. When it happened, the creation time of the file was in year 1906. It's very unclear because it's impossible to reproduce and I only got some information via an anonymous crash report of our software.